# Execute C Program On MySQL Database Insertion

Tags: c

I'm wondering how to design such a program for Linux Ubuntu. Essentially, I'm envisioning a small program that runs continuously on the Linux machine, listening for a MySQL database table insertion for a specific table that is specified. When the program detects that a row has been inserted into the database, it would execute a C program (the program in question is currently run by cd'ing to the directory and typing "./simulator" in Terminal. I'm wondering how I could achieve something like this.

I've tried doing this with MySQL triggers, something like [this](http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html) but I'm not sure how to install LIB_MYSQLUDF_SYS (I've gotten a lot of errors).

If anyone can suggest a simple and straightforward way to achieve this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well as for other people that udf lib does seem to work I'd suggest you try getting that thing to work.  But we'll need more info than "a lot of errors" to help you there.

Comment: I couldn't really find detailed instructions on how to install the library, I just had all the files in a directory and I typed "sudo make". The error I got was `gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -I. -shared lib_mysqludf_sys.c -o /usr/lib/lib_mysqludf_sys.so
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cck1TT89.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against .rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`. I looked at using gcc -fPIC but I'm exactly sure how to use it.

Comment: The very same blog page you link to gives a solution for these known problems when compiling for 64 bits, in the comments.

Comment: I added -fPIC to the Makefile as suggested and I was able to make without any errors.

Comment: Great :-)  Have fun with your new udf

Comment: I'm getting an error: `#1305 - FUNCTION simulator.sys_exec does not exist`. I see `lib_mysqludf_sys.so` in `/usr/lib` so I'm assuming that the UDF is successfully installed. My trigger code is `DELIMITER @@
CREATE TRIGGER startSimulator 
BEFORE INSERT ON trigger
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
 DECLARE result int(10);
 SET cmd=CONCAT('/home/lab/Dropbox/simulator/version_unified/./simulator');
 SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END;
@@
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: Did you register the function(s) with create function as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/udf-compiling.html)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. As I said I see `lib_mysqludf_sys.so` in `/usr/lib` so I'm assuming the UDF is installed properly. When I make it again it says `make: Nothing to be done for lib_mysqludf_sys.so.`

Comment: Please read [the UDF installation procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/udf-compiling.html) I link to and especially the section starting with "After the shared object file has been installed, notify mysqld about the new functions with the following statements.".  mysqld needs to be notified about the installation of the UDF, it won't just pick them up like that.

Comment: I followed the instructions, but now I am getting a different error. Whenever I try to insert a row into the "trigger" table that I specified in the MySQL trigger, I get `#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query`. However, other queries that insert rows into other tables work fine.

Comment: Anything interesting in the logfile?

Comment: Both `/var/log/mysql.err` and `/var/log/mysql.log` are empty.

Comment: I suggest you open a new question starting with at least your trigger code in it, a description of what that simulator program actually does (which may explain why it explodes in this context), and the error message, because we're already miles away from the original scope of this question.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all of your help.

Comment: np, i'll monitor the new questions and lend a hand if I can.  Good luck :-)

Comment: I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733636/mysql-trigger-error-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative way I accomplished this using the PHP `exec` function to call the server-side C program immediately after the database insertion. This method works, because I was both inserting and reading from the database table.