# MySQL Trigger Error #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: c++, mysql, triggers

I want to create a MySQL trigger in which I execute a C++ program when a row is inserted into a MySQL table. To do this, I am using LIB_MYSQLUDF_SYS, which I successfully installed as a UDF. My code is based off [this](http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html) tutorial.

Here is my trigger code:

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE TRIGGER startSimulator 
BEFORE INSERT ON `trigger`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
 DECLARE result int(10);
 SET cmd=CONCAT('/home/lab/Dropbox/simulator/version_unified/./simulator');
 SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END;
@@
DELIMITER ;
```

In case it is unclear, the system program is executed using `./simulator`. However, when I use `INSERT INTO trigger (trigger) VALUES (yes)` to insert a row into the "trigger" table, I get the following error:

`#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

When I remove the trigger, the query executes fine. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this happens?

`mysqld --log-warnings=2` yields:

```
130719 15:53:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
130719 15:53:59 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
130719 15:53:59 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130719 15:53:59 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130719 15:53:59 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
130719 15:53:59 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130719 15:53:59 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130719 15:53:59  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Comment: What OS?  Are there firewalls in that OS?